# Upgrading Meteor: Error when running mrt migrate-app

Tags: meteor

I just upgraded Meteor to 0.9.0 and I got an error when running "mrt migrate-app".

Have I done something wrong?

```
-- Notice --

0.9.0: Welcome to the new Meteor package system! You can now add any Meteor
   package to your app (from more than 1800 packages available on the
   Meteor Package Server) just by typing 'meteor add <packagename>', no
   Meteorite required.

   It looks like you have been using Meteorite with this project. To
   migrate your project automatically to the new system:
     (1) upgrade your Meteorite with 'npm install -g meteorite', then
     (2) run 'mrt migrate-app' inside the project.
   Having done this, you no longer need 'mrt' and can just use 'meteor'.


All your package dependencies are already up to date.
me@ubuntu:~/myApp$ mrt migrate-app

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/bin/mrt.js:21
 throw("Subcommand " + subCommandName + " does not exist!");
```

First of all I did this (and it seemed to work):

```
me@ubuntu:/usr/local/lib/node_modules$ sudo npm install -g meteorite
```

Comment: I have the same thing going on here. `mrt` is not up to date I think!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you have to update the project

```
meteor update
```

Then make sure to update meteorite

```
sudo npm update -g meteorite
```

And then run

```
mrt migrate-app
```

For more info read:

- http://blog.percolatestudio.com/engineering/meteor-packaging-questions/
  (Especially: *How do I migrate my app from Meteorite to the Meteor Package System (0.9.0) ?*)
- https://hackpad.com/Migrating-Apps-UfPrM192vSQ
- And personal favorite: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/updating-to-090/

Comment: this doesn't work for me. If I do these steps (again) I end up with the same result

Comment: Does running `mrt --version ` give you 0.9.0 ? (Other than that unfortunately I cannot reproduce the issue)

Comment: This worked for me but some of the packages themselves haven't yet been migrated

Comment: I solved the issue. For some reason I have a `mrt` file in /usr/local/bin and one somewhere in my home directory. I tried both and the one in my home dir worked :)

Comment: Not having some packages migrated is normal since they are not present in the new "atmosphere". For more information about the new packages read: http://blog.percolatestudio.com/engineering/meteor-packaging-questions/

Comment: I had the same issue. `/usr/bin/mrt migrate-app` worked for me.

Comment: It is also possible that some packages have been updated but that `mrt migrate-app` will still fail, since the package isn't registered with a meteor developer account.  The solution is to remove those packages, do the migrate-app, and then do a search with `meteor search package` and then add them back with the new name: `meteor add author:package-name-here`

Answer (score 0):

I'm on osx and my mrt --version was 0.7.1 so I did a

```
macport selfupdate
```

then a

```
sudo port update npm
```

and a rehash to refresh the mrt executable (symlink to a js-file (I'm using zsh). Thank you to Matyas.

Then I did the

```
sudo npm update -g meteorite
mrt migrate-app
```

again but had a 'npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator' which was solved with a

```
chown -R myUsername:staff .npm
```

regards
Claus

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with

```
sudo mrt migrate-app
```

I don't know the possible consequences of this, use at your own risk!