# How to upgrade a meteor app from 0.9.4 to 1.0.0?

Tags: meteor, upgrade

Meteor example app, microscope has version 0.9.4, when I try use `meteor run` command to launch application .

There have a print:
Sorry, this project uses Meteor METEOR@0.9.4, which is not installed and
could not be downloaded. Please check to make sure that you are online.

I am behind a proxy in corporate.

When I install the Meteor, only latest 1.0.0 can be installed.

- How can I do?
- Upgrade the app to 1.0.0, and how?
- Downgrade the meteor to 0.9.4, and how?

I tried use `meteor update --release 0.9.4`, not work or using `meteor update`, other error pop up:

```
/home/hunter/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.hgbesu++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:206
                                                throw(ex);

..
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=socket hang up
    at Object.Future.wait (/home/hunter/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.hgbesu++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
    at _.extend._createSocket (packages/ddp/stream_client_nodejs.js:265)
    at _.extend._launchConnection (packages/ddp/stream_client_nodejs.js:142)
    at new LivedataTest.ClientStream (packages/ddp/stream_client_nodejs.js:28)
    at new Connection (packages/ddp/livedata_connection.js:52)
    at Object.DDP.connect (packages/ddp/livedata_connection.js:1581)
```

This should proxy issue.

No document there after search.

Answer (score 14):

I was able to successfully update a project from 0.9.3.1 to 1.1 with:

```
meteor update
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `meteor run` like this:

```
meteor run --release
```

…won’t upgrade your meteor installation, but will download the `--release` and run the current app with it.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue after updating meteor to 1.4.1. I happened to fix it with this help [Github Issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7317)

1. Reset your app

   > meteor reset
2. Install npm with meteor again

   > meteor npm install
3. Rebuild npm (Optional)

   > meteor npm rebuild

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late and slightly different:  I have a similar problem when I upgraded from 1.0.3.1 to 1.0.3.2.  After reading the answers here, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25511580/upgrading-meteor-error-when-running-mrt-migrate-app), I tried the following which worked for me:

```
meteor update --release <new version>
```

replacing `<new version>` with the latest version you're running.  This updated my project, and subsequent runs using `meteor` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was to update by change the file .meteor/release to meteor 1.0. I had packages issues, I also noticed that iron router inner actions changed (I fixed this by fixing the files load order) and on Meteor 1.0 you’ve a package for everything.

Try to add the package `meteor-platform`, it’s a meta package that contains the most used packages.

I also had issue with some atmosphere packages, it’s a tough job to upgrade it.